# Used circle cutter in wrong place in drywall, best repair method?

Tags: drywall, walls, mounting

I'm mounting a TV and used a circle cutter attachment on my drill in the wrong location.

I cut through 2 1/2" sheets of drywall and still have the discs of drywall.

What is the best method to repair the hole? The bracket will be covering the hole anyways so I am not sure it is necessary to repair but it maybe nicer if I ever move out etc.

Comment: So how big are these holes, anyway? Your question not-quite-clearly states that holes were cut in 2 sheets of 1/2" sheetrock, and that you still have the cut-outs, leading me (for one) to believe that the holes are fairly large?  ;-)

Answer (score 24):

Cut some short strips of plywood or even paneling (long enough to overlap both sides of the hole by a couple of inches). Don't cut your fingers off.

Put the plywood strip(s) in the hole and position the strip so it is extending out beyond both edges of the hole, *behind* the sheetrock.

Hold the strip tightly by pulling outward on the back of strip with your fingers, and drive  screws through the sheetrock and through the plywood strips.

Now, put the sheetrock cut-out back in place, and screw it to the plywood strip(s).

Patch the sheetrock.

Comment: +1 for good advice, +10 for "Don't cut your fingers off"

Comment: Paint stir sticks are a cheap alternative that doesn't involve power tools.

Comment: With a paint stick, I usually use construction adhesive or wood glue instead of drywall screws. But either way works great.

Comment: It's all fun and games until you cut your fingers off. The paint stir sticks are a good idea. I'm pretty sure I've used those, too--whatever was handy.

Comment: It is also possible to put the backing in as above, then fill the hole with plaster (US: mud?) and then sand to a fine finish.  (More useful if you don't have nice clean cutouts to fill the hole with.)

Answer (score 4):

If the hole is fairly small (say <4" diameter), then you can likely get away with just covering the hole with fiber mesh tape and using a hard setting compound (e.g. Sheetrock 90) to fill the hole.

For larger holes Craig has the "best" method, but I've used this method successfully for holes in plaster and drywall up to 3.5" diameter.

Comment: The OP did not say the holes were 2-1/2" in diameter, but rather that holes were cut through 2 (two) sheets of 1/2" sheetrock. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Drywall patches are available at most home improvement stores.  I've personally never used one, so I can't say how well they work (if at all). Though for the couple of dollars they cost, it might be worth a try.

There are self adhesive patches like this one available at most home improvement stores.

[Wal-Board Tools 4" x 4" Drywall Repair Patch](http://m.homedepot.com/p/Wal-Board-Tools-4-in-x-4-in-Drywall-Repair-Self-Adhesive-Wall-Patch-54-005/100403176)

[image: Wal-Board Tools 4" x 4" Drywall Repair Patch]
<sub>(source: [homedepot.com](http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/productImages/300/6b/6bded6fd-5bf7-4de6-97e1-98a748400556_300.jpg))</sub>

Again, I've never used this or any other similar product. I do not endorse or recommend the use of this specific product.

Comment: If you squeeze enough drywall compound through that metal mesh to sort of fill the hole behind it and stiffen it up so it won't flex after it sets, or if the hole is fairly small, these aren't bad.